# Is the Riemann integral of a strictly positive function strictly positive?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

If f is a strictly positive Riemann integrable function defined on a closed and bounded interval. Then, is it necessary that f has strictly positive Riemann integral value?
f need not be continuous.
I was trying to construct some example similar to [Thomae function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) but such that it is strictly positive but in that case I was getting integral to be strictly positive.

Comment: Just intuitively, if for all $x$ the values $f(x)$ lie above the $x$-axis, then their average value (this is what the integral gives you) cannot be below the $x$-axis

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/996282/is-there-a-function-f-gt-0-such-that-int-f-dx-0

Answer (score 5):

Hint: The set of discontinuity points of a Riemann integrable function has Lebesgue measure zero. In particular, it is continuous at some point of the interval.

Comment: +1: Nice approach.