# Integrate $\int_0^{\int_0^{\vdots}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x$ and monotonicity of integrals

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

I must evaluate
$$\int_0^{\int_0^{\vdots}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x$$
My idea is that if we set
$$L:=\int_0^{\vdots}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x$$
Then the integral must satisfy the equation
$$\int_0^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x=L$$
And we have that
$$\int_0^L \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x=\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int_\varepsilon^L\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x=2\sqrt{L}$$
So we have the equation $2\sqrt{L}=L$, that leads to the solutions $L_1=0$ and $L_2=4$; now I suspect that
$$\int_0^{\int_0^{\vdots}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\text{d}x > 0$$
So the only choice left if $L_2=4$, but I don't actually know how to prove it rigorously; I'm sure that the last integral is $\geq0$ because $\sqrt{x}\geq0$, but maybe it is $>0$ because the square root can't be $0$ being at the denominator.

Two questions:

1) is my argument right? I'm not sure if it is rigorous, especially when I "substitute" the upper bound with $L$; maybe I can approach it with sequences.

2) In this case the square root was at the denominator so somehow I've excluded the fact that the integrand could be $\geq0$ (if my argument is correct), but in general how can I prove that if $f(x)>0$ then $\int_a^b f(x) \text{d}x >0$ and not $\int_a^b f(x)\text{d}x \geq 0$ (if this is true)?

Thanks.

Comment: Your expression makes no sense, at least not  to me.The upper bound of the upper bound is a bunch of dots. Can you put the expression in the form of  function  of x to be integrated from x=number to x=another number?

Comment: @P.Lawrence Thanks for your interest. It means that the upper bound goes like that an infinite amount of times, like $x^{x^{x^{\dots}}}$ means "$x$ to the power of $x$ to..." an infinite amount of times.

Comment: Actually, both the values can be considered since there is no meaningful interpretation of the integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) is my argument right? I'm not sure if it is rigorous, especially when I "substitute" the upper bound with L; maybe I can approach it with sequences.

The question isn't even properly posed, as

$$\int_0^{\int_0^\vdots\frac1{\sqrt x}~\mathrm dx}\frac1{\sqrt x}~\mathrm dx$$

isn't a meaningful expression. You want to instead consider something such as:

$$a_0=\alpha\ge0\\a_{n+1}=\int_0^{a_n}\frac1{\sqrt x}~\mathrm dx=2\sqrt{a_n}$$

and ask what

$$L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n$$

is. It can easily be seen that if $\alpha=0$, then $L=a_n=0$ for all $n$. If $0<a_n<4$, then we have

$$a_n<2\sqrt{a_n}=a_{n+1}<4$$

and if $a_n>4$, then we have

$$4<a_{n+1}=2\sqrt{a_n}<a_n$$

so for any $\alpha>0$, it converges, since $a_n$ is monotone and bounded. Now that you know that it converges, it suffices to solve

$$L=2\sqrt L$$

restricted to the interval that we know the solution is in (from the bounds), which in this case gives $L=4$.

> 2) In this case the square root was at the denominator so somehow I've excluded the fact that the integrand could be $\ge0$ (if my argument is correct), but in general how can I prove that if $f(x)>0$ then $\int^b_af(x)dx>0$ and not $\int^b_af(x)dx\ge0$ (if this is true)?

This is not true unless $a<b$ and $f$ is Riemann integrable, in which case you can see [Is the Riemann integral of a strictly positive function positive?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/351157/272831).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is all clear except one thing: when you are considering $\alpha=0$ we have $\int_0^0 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \text{d}x$; now I know that $\int_a^a f(x) \text{d}x=0$, but $f$ is divergent when $x \to 0$.
Why can we say that the integral is $0$? It is because $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is integrable when $x \to 0$? Are there some cases where I can't say that $\int_a^a f(x) \text{d}x = 0$, for example if $f$ hasn't finite integral for $x \to a$?

Comment: These are improper Riemann integrals, so we are interpreting it as $\lim_{a,b\to0^+}\int_a^b\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt x}$, which is zero. In fact, if this converges, then it will always be zero.

Answer (score 4):

1)

I'll try to make it more rigorous.
Let
$$
a_0= \int_0^\alpha \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d}x = 2 \sqrt{\alpha}\\[3ex]
a_{n+1}=\int_0^{a_n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \mathrm{d}x = 2 \sqrt{a_n}
$$
for some $\alpha \ge 0$. We are interested in evalulate

$$L=\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n. $$
From the general equation we have
$$L =2 \sqrt{L} $$
so if we suppose the limit exists, then *a priori* we have three possibilities:

1. $L=0$;
2. $L=4$;
3. $L= +\infty$.

Notice that for the first terms of the sequence we have
$$
a_0 = 2 \alpha^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
a_1 = 2 \sqrt{a_0}= 2 \sqrt{2 \alpha^{\frac{1}{2}}} = 2 \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{2}}  \cdot\alpha^{\frac{1}{2^2}}\\
a_2 =  2 \sqrt{a_1} = 2 \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{2}} \cdot 2^{\frac{1}{2^2}}\cdot\alpha^{\frac{1}{2^3}}
$$

and, in general,
$$
a_n=2^{\sum_{i=0}^n \big(\frac{1}{2}\big)^i} \cdot \alpha^{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}
$$
(note that if $\alpha = 0$ then $a_n = 0$ for every $n > 0$ ).

So, since
$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^i = \frac{1-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}{1 - \frac{1}{2}} = 2 - \frac{1}{2^n}
$$
(see [Formula for geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) ), we get

$$
a_n = 4 \cdot 2^\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \cdot  \alpha^{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}}
$$
Now 
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}=2^0=1$$
and hence if $\alpha \neq 0$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}a_n = 4 \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} 2^\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty}\alpha^{\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}} = 4 \cdot\lim_{n \to \infty}\exp \left( \frac{\ln \alpha}{2^{n+1}} \right) = 4 \cdot\exp \left(\ln \alpha\cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} \right)=4 \cdot e^0 = 4
$$
finally

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \begin{cases} 0 & \text{if  $\alpha =
 0$}; \\ 4 & \text{if  $\alpha > 0$} \\ \end{cases} $$

2)
Riemann integral has the monotonicity proprierties, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994927/real-analysis-riemann-integration-strict-monotonicity-for-integrals?noredirect=1&lq=1) for more details.

Comment: the fact that there are only 3 apriori possibilities assumes the limit exists. it's prolly not hard to show limit exists, but you should address it

Comment: This Is true, thank you! I should have written "the possibile limits are..."