# Is there a function $f \gt 0$ such that $\int f dx=0$?

Tags: integration, analysis

If $$f \ge 0$$, then $$\int f dx \ge 0$$.

There is a function such that

$$f \gt 0$$ but $$\int f dx=0$$?

Comment: What's your domain of integration?

Comment: Oh sorry.A domain is closed interval [a,b]

Comment: Then such function doesn't exist. You can find a proof below. You can also argue it by using the fact $f$ is Riemann integrable $\iff$ it's bounded and continuous almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for commet. Can I do this without measure theory??

Answer (score 1):

If you choose your domain of integration be a measure zero set, then any Lebesgue integrable (in particular Riemann integrable) function has zero integral.

If you consider Riemann integrable function on $[a,b]$ with  $a<b$, then it's not possible, see a proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994927/real-analysis-riemann-integration-strict-monotonicity-for-integrals/994939#994939).